# Text vanishes when soup produces

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I am trying to extract the date from the Yahoo Finance site but when the text is produce only the time appears without the date

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

technicals = {}
ticker = "INFY.NS"

try:
    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + ticker + "/key-statistics?p=" + ticker
    r = requests.get(url)
    # soup = BeautifulSoup(open("Yahoo Stats.html"), 'lxml')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    t = soup.find('span', {"class": "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"})
    technicals["CMP"] = t.text
    # d = soup.find('span', {"class": "C($tertiaryColor) D(b) Fz(12px) Fw(n) Mstart(0)--mobpsm Mt(6px)--mobpsm"})
    d = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'quote-market-notice'})
    print(d.text)
```

The code runs further on.

Can somebody help get the **date** and time

Answer (score 1):

As I checked the page source the data is not located in the *span* tag. It seems that it is loaded dynamically.

```
<span data-reactid="36">At close:  3:30PM IST</span>
```

I recommend you to use ***Selenium*** library instead to get the required data.